# Concurrent calls to a custom plugin processed 1 at a time

Tags: java, neo4j

I developed a plugin of my own in Neo4j in order to speed the process of inserting node. Mainly because I needed to insert node and relationship only if they didn't exists before which can be too slow using the REST API.

If I try to call my plugin a 100 time, inserting roughly 100 nodes and 100 relationship each time, it take approximately 350ms on each call. Each call is inserting different nodes, in order to rule out locking cause.

However if I parallelize my calls (2, 3 , 4... at time), the response time drop accordingly to the parallelism degree. It takes 750ms to insert my 200 objects when I do 2 call at a time, 1000ms when I do 3 etc.

I'm calling my plugin from a .NET MVC controller, using HttpWebRequest. I set the maxConnection to 10000, and I can see all the TCP connection opened.

I investigated a little on this issue but it seems very wrong. I must have done something wrong, either in my neo4j configuration, or in my plugin code. Using VisualVM I found out that the threads launched by Neo4j to handle my calls are working sequentially. See the picture linked.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IJ8s.png

My conf :
Windows 8, 2 core
8G of RAM
Neo4j 2.0M03 installed as a service with no conf tuning

Hope someone will be able to help me. As it is, I will be unable to use Neo4j in production, where there will be tens of concurrent calls, which cannot be done sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j is transactional. Every commit triggers an IO operation on filesystem which needs to run in a synchronized block - this explains the picture you've attached. Therefore it's best practice to run writes single threaded. Any pre-processing prior can of course benefit from parallelizing.

In general for maximum performance go with the stable version (1.9.2 as of today). Early milestone builds are not optimized yet, so you might get a wrong picture.

Another thing to consider is the transaction size used in your plugin. 10k to 50k in a single transaction should give you best results. If your transactions are very small, transactional overhead is significant, in case of huge transactions, you need lots of memory.

Write performance is heavily driven by the performance of underlying IO subsystem. If possible use fast SSD drives, even better stripe then.

Comment: Ok, I understand better. Indeed, working with a single thread but putting a lot of data per call, I average 2 graph object (node or relationship) per ms inserted. Thanks for the insights